# Get all Test Sets given a Test Set Folder path in ALM REST API

Tags: rest, hp-alm

I'm using PHP to get all the testcases in all testsets in a given folder.

I followed this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087313/4571742) to make the connection and I'm using [the following query](http://qcurl/qcbin/rest/domains/mydomain/projects/myproject/test-set-folders?query=%7Bname['FOLDERNAME']%7D%22);) to get the `id` of the test-set-folder I want as my root:

So this give me an `id=12345` for example.

How can I get all the testcases below this testset folder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So after some investigation I finally managed to solve my question so I will share what I learned.

**LOGIN TO QC REST:**
http://IP:PORT/qcbin/rest/is-authenticated?login-form-required=y

**GET DATA FOR SPECIFIC FOLDER:**
http://IP:PORT/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/test-set-folders?query={name['MYFOLDER']}

From the previous call we get many values. We will use the `hierarchical-path` and use it in the next request. Note the *. This is to get all the test sets bellow the hierarchical-path selected.

**GET ALL TESTSETS BELOW THE FOLDER IN THE PREVIOUS STEP:**
http://IP:PORT/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/test-sets?query={test-set-folder.hierarchical-path[hierarchical-path*]}

Here we get results for each testset. We can get the `id` and `name` of each testset among other data. We will use the `id` on the next query to get the Test Cases

**GET ALL TESTCASES FOR EACH TESTSET (ID):**
http://IP:PORT/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/test-instances?query={cycle-id[ID]}

Finally, we can get more data from specific test cases, using the `test-id` returned from the last step.

**GET TESTCASE DETAILS:**
http://IP:PORT/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/tests/TEST_ID

Comment: Thank Zephirus, I voted up. Just quickly have you tried CRUD operations, I have wanted to update a test case run as 'Pass' or 'Fail' do you have any sample on that... thank you.

Comment: Hi. I'm able to update test instances, not runs. I use this url: "http://IP:PORT/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/test-instances/TESTINSTANCE_ID". You have to send the data in XML format like this: http://pastebin.com/xtc9cN0B. Sample core (not tested) here: http://pastebin.com/JJsJSGYf

Comment: Zephirus, thank you. To be honest I am trying to understand how this rest api works. I am able to get the data if I use browser request and now I have no idea how to put/post the data to ALM. I thought I need to install curl and I did it but again don't know how to send the request struggling a bit... I am trying... if you already have experience in this if possible kindly give simple example. very basic knowledge how this api works. thank you.

Comment: Please add me to skype if you want. It's in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

How to send multiple queries in order to sort large data

for example
`http://IP:PORT/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/tests?query={owner['MYNAME']}` gives 1000 results.

But in order to sort one or two fields to filter results:

1. `owner['MYNAME'] and user-05['PLATFORM']` so I get 200 results
2. `owner['MYNAME'] and user-05['PLATFORM'] and user-03['REGRESSION']` so I get 10 results

Thanks,
Sandeep S K.

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple queries in order to sort large data, You can use semi-colon separated queries inside the curly brace. E.g. below -

https://host/qcbin/rest/domains/your_domain/projects/your_project/test-sets?query={user-02[userId];name['script']}

To get 10 results - you can do something like this -

It will look like -

https://host/qcbin/rest/domains/your_domain/projects/your_project/test-sets?query={owner['MYNAME'];user-05['PLATFORM'];user-03['REGRESSION']}