# HP ALM Accessing Test Plan via REST API (C#)

Tags: c#, rest, alm

I am trying to access test set data in QC/ALM via C# and the REST API, but I am struggling to with path navigation.

In Test Lab we have a path of:

```
Root
  UnitTests
    QA-US
    QA-UK
      Product1
        ...
      Product2
        Test Campaign 1
        Test Campaign 2
          RC 1
          RC 2
```

I am trying to access test run details for a campaign (e.g. Test Campaign 1, RC 2) but I can't figure out how I do this.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249059/get-all-test-sets-given-a-test-set-folder-path-in-alm-rest-api/33278828) Stack Overflow question but I couldn't figure out the hierarchy path.

I attempted to use: http://IP:PORT/qcbin/rest/domains/THEDOMAIN/projects/THEPROJECT/test-set-folders?query={name['Root']} and get details back, but if I want a want a deeper path .. e.g. 'Root\UnitTests\QA-UK\Product2\Test Campaign 1\RC 1' it fails to be found.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get folder level sets using following way. Filter on name will not work. You need to filter on parent-id. Even though it is id field still HP accepts folder name. Following query works on my HPALM instance and hopefully it will work with yours as well.

```
http://host:port/qcbin/rest/domains/DEFAULT/projects/TestP/test-sets?query={parent-id[^Root\Path 1\Path 2^]}.
```

Regards

Gaurav

Comment: Hi, thank you I am getting closer now (which is a big improvement) ... Does Query need another argument if I want a specific test set within a folder - e.g. for Nov 2018 we have 5 RC test sets within the folder and I want to access RC4.

Comment: @GemmaMorriss can you please mark this answer as accepted