# HP ALM REST API Update with PHP

Tags: php, rest, hp-alm

In this link - [HP ALM REST API login using PHP CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283687/hp-alm-rest-api-login-using-php-curl/13087313) - it's explained how to login to HP ALM REST API using PHP.

I followed that answer and I'm able to login and retrieve information from QC but I need to update values and I can't find information on the documentation on how to do it. Anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always refer to the library below:

http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/REST/webframe.htm#Overview.htm

There you will find all the basic actions you can send to your server.
Question is too generic and can just be answered as it is :-)
Have a nice day.